# openpose extract only the skeleton

Tags: openpose

I'm using [openpose](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose) in a [docker container](https://github.com/seancook/docker-openpose-cpu). 
The following command create images, where the detected keypoints are printed on the original images.

```
openpose -display=0 -image_dir=/data -write_images=/data -face=true -hand=true
```

I would like to have the keypoints without the original image on a black background. Like shown here:
[image: wanted result]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `--disable_blending` flag, as explained here: https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/master/doc/01_demo.md#main-flags

> `--disable_blending`: If enabled, it will render the results (keypoint skeletons or heatmaps) on a black background, not showing the original image. Related: `part_to_show`, `alpha_pose`, and `alpha_pose`.

Comment: the GitHub link u have provided is removed. anyhow I would like to draw this skeleton using scikit or any other libraries after processing the video/image any idea on that?

Comment: Thanks, @MohamedSajjadh! Updated the link to the doc.
I'm not familiar with those other libraries so I cannot help you with those with my current knowledge.